# how to work with "Tabsselect" event jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-tabs

i have two tabs tabfirst, tabsecond.

whenever i select a tab(first or second) i have to bind some actions to other tab. So how i can do that?

```
$("tabs").bind('tabsselect',function(){
   if(Selected tab==first)
       //ignore validations in tab 2
   else 
       //ignore validations in tab 1
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
$('.tabs li').bind('click', function() {
  if($(this).attr('id') == 'first')
  {
    alert('First tab selected');
  }
});
```

Comment: i have two tabs in a >div< >ul< >li< >li<. So when i do like you said it activattes the div click not the li clicks...